# which canvas framework use to work with geometric figures?

Tags: canvas, frameworks, html5-canvas, easeljs, paperjs

I want to develop a small demo project with geometric figures, having the possibility to add / remove corners, get the length of each side and drag and drop of the corners and so on.

Which framework I should use (easelJS, threeJS, paperJS, fabricJS...) considering the versatility and the ease to use of each framwework?

Comment: When you focus on editing geometric shapes, you might consider using SVG instead of canvas.

Comment: OK @Philipp. Thanks. I'll start study SVG.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with paperjs quite a bit and was impressed with how quickly I could get really far. I was also playing around with geometric shapes that I needed to scale based on canvas size.

All the tech you mentioned are quite good though.

If you want to learn paper.js, why not have a look at this screencast I created? 
http://tagtree.tv/canvas-with-paper-js

It should be perfect for what you would like to do.